SingleUser and bound service model in android
I'm new to android and I'm trying to achieve the following use-case,
I need to implement a service component running as singleUser (android:singleUser="false") to store the data across users. The data is not specific to the user so need to manage them across users. My understanding is, running the service as singleUser will make it store the data under user0. However, it restricts the client components also to be running in the user0 in order to bind with my service and access the data. Hence, I'm exploring options to run my service as singleUser and at the same time, let the clients run in active user space and communicate with my service. Clients will not have INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission.
Can someone help me understand what is the correct way to implement this?
I went though this doc https://source.android.com/docs/devices/admin/multiuser-apps but I don't quite understand the proxy component model mentioned in the first diagram.
I'm assuming that I need to create a singleUser service which deals with the data and create a separate bound service (running in active user space) for clients to bind to. The bound service will in turn communicate with singleUser service to access and return the data to the clients. This model requires just the INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS (without FULL) permission. Is my understanding correct?
